# Testing REST API provider response without mock

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, pact

Currently, I am working on a project on Spring Boot where we are integrating with external REST API. As part of our integration suite test, we are doing the mock test of the actual external API which executes as part of the CI/CD.

My question is in production it calls the actual API so, how we can do that in the test environment. I don't think we need to make the actual external provider call during multiple integration test which will load the external API, also at the same time would like to test with actual REST response from the service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/). Or sure, use Pact, given that you've already used that tag.

Comment: In the past I have used a static .json file that can be requested from a server containing fixtured data. Or you could setup a simple Flask / Express.js simulator service. It is not uncommon to setup a simulator, you are correct that making the real call is perhaps not practical, especially if the service costs money per request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. I am using pact by defining the request, response in a json file with different scenarios. But this is kind of one way because the provider never going to verify the contract, unlike consumer. I am not sure though, how the public API providers are making sure their changes are not breaking the existing clients, specifically when the APIs are public and there are hundreds/Ks of clients.

Comment: Typically, public APIs use semantic versioning of the API to introduce breaking changes. Hopefully they are following good process! 
Though it's not really recommended, you  _can_ use pact for testing public APIs, and do the verification step yourself, but it's a bit fiddly. You have to use the API to set up the data for the provider states before you can execute the API request that is actually in the pact test.

Comment: how about using `TestRestTemplate` for those external API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the public API has a swagger description, you could use the [Atlassian Pact Swagger Validator](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator). I describe the workflow in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79GKBYSqMIo#t=39m10s

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to create a mock API for the external service. There are some free services like https://mockfirst.com, https://www.mockable.io/, etc.  where you can do that.